# Unresolved kotlin android extensions

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I've noticed that after `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha3'` to my build.gradle kotlin android extensions stop working.

Imports like this `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<some layout>.*`  became unused and all layout ids became unresolved.

I've tried to add `androidExtensions {experimental = true}` to build.gradle, but it didn't help.

Has anyone faced the same issue? Is there a solution for that?

I use AS 3.2 canary 17 and kotlin 1.2.41

Update: this happens only in fragments

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: Did you re-sync and rebuild? I always get R.id s unresolved after changing up gradle without rebuild.

Comment: I've tried tosync, rebuild, invalidate cache and restart. Error message `Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch`. Everything works if I delete com.google.android.material dependency.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Got the same problem using the latest Material library beta

Comment: Yes, I've solved it by replacing all dependencies wit this: `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-beta01"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. In my case, what causes the problem is 
`implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.2.1'`